# Scrapy: check whether page contains HTML Form element

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I need a scrapy script which explores **the whole** website and only saves the pages that have a `form` HTML tag within them.

Here's my current approach which is not working properly

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'mps'
        allowed_domains = ['some.url.com']
        start_urls = ['https://some.url.com/']

        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )

        def parse_item(self, response):
            hasForm = response.xpath("//form[@id = 'aspnetForm']/form").extract_first(default='not-found')
            if hasForm == 'not-found':
                pass
            else:
                filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.body)
                pass
```

**Update:**

I also need to exclude `form` with a particular id

Comment: Have you tested in the scrapy shell to see if the form is in the response scrapy sees?

Comment: @tomjn no and I didn't quite get what you mean

Comment: run `scrapy shell https://some.url.com/` then `response.xpath("//form")` and see if it finds anything

Comment: @tomjn it does find some forms. I need to find all the forms except one with a given id

Comment: Ok- and you say that `response.xpath("//form[@id='aspnetForm']")` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mps'
    allowed_domains = ['some.url.com']
    start_urls = ['https://some.url.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hasForm = response.xpath("//form").extract_first(default='not-found')            
        if hasForm != 'not-found':
            page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
            filename = 'test-%s.html' % page
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
```